# VARCHAR column breaks Hibernate quietly when content is more than 141 characters

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, orm

We have a very strange issue using Spring Boot (v2.1.5) and Hibernate (5.3.10). We have a table `DocumentRevision` which has foreign keys e.g. `Document -> DocumentRevision -> User`. When we fetch `Document`, `DocumentRevision` is eager-fetched, and `User` is lazy-fetched. This is working correctly in most cases, but failing in very specific cases and in a very specific way.

`DocumentRevision` actually has two foreign keys to `User`: `uploader (NOT NULL)` and `approver (NULL)`.

One of the columns in `DocumentRevision` is `source VARCHAR(255) NULL`.

When `DocumentRevision.source` contains *142 or more characters in length*, `uploader` is not fetched by Hibernate, and a `NullPointerException` results. For the same record, when the `source` column is `null` or 0-141 characters in length, the `uploader` is correctly fetched. This is 100% reproducible, 142 characters is the breaking point. And note, these are ASCII characters, nothing special (collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`).

- completely filling all other `VARCHAR` fields in a non-broken record has no effect -- everything works correctly (it is literally only the `source` column which causes this issue, and only when it contains 142 or more characters)
- I can break a non-broken record by inserting 142 or more characters in the `source` column
- setting `approverId` to `null` for a broken record fixes the issue
- setting it to a valid user's id, but a different one than `uploaderId` *does not* fix the issue
- when both `creator` and `approver` hold the exact same value in the database (point to the same `User`), hibernate is able to fetch `approver` but not `creator` -- that is, when I examine the resulting `Document`, its `DocumentRevision` does not have a `creator`, but it *does* have an `approver` -- **this is only true when debugging and inspecting the value**
- turning on SQL logging shows X statements executed for a broken record and X+3 for a non-broken record -- the additional SQL statements are related to fetching the User (they simply do not happen in the broken case)

**Debugging Failures**

I've tried the following with the same results.

1. increase size of `source` column
2. replace `@Column` annotation with `@Column(length = X)`
3. rename table
4. rename column
5. upgrade Spring / Hibernate
6. mark `uploader` as `FetchType.EAGER`
7. remove `optional = false` from `uploader`

*Update:* We've noticed that this can also be fixed by removing the many-to-one relationship from `Document` to `DocumentRevision` (`Document.documentRevisions`). Also, removing the one-to-one relationship from `DocumentRevision` to `Document` (`DocumentRevision.document`) fixes the issue. My current theory is some sort of circular reference -- but again, nothing from Hibernate in the logs.

Here are some snippets:

**Table: Document**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Document` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deletedDateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sectionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `currentRevisionId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_Document_sectionId_Section_id` (`sectionId`),
  KEY `FK_Document_currentRevisionId_DocumentRevision_id` (`currentRevisionId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Document_currentRevisionId_DocumentRevision_id` FOREIGN KEY (`currentRevisionId`) REFERENCES `DocumentRevision` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Document_sectionId_Section_id` FOREIGN KEY (`sectionId`) REFERENCES `Section` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34074 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Table: DocumentRevision**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `DocumentRevision` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deletedDateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `contentLength` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uploaderId` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `approverId` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fileId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parsed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourcePublishDateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coordinateSystem` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mgrs` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourceUrl` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `marking` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `approvedDateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_DocumentRevision_fileId_Document_id` (`fileId`),
  KEY `FK_DocumentRevision_uploaderId_User_id` (`uploaderId`),
  KEY `FK_DocumentRevision_approverId_User_id` (`approverId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DocumentRevision_approverId_User_id` FOREIGN KEY (`approverId`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DocumentRevision_fileId_Document_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fileId`) REFERENCES `Document` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DocumentRevision_uploaderId_User_id` FOREIGN KEY (`uploaderId`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34080 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Table: User**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `createdDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deletedDateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `primaryEmailAddress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_Person_username` (`username`),
  KEY `IDX_Person_primaryEmailAddress` (`primaryEmailAddress`),
  KEY `IDX_Person_lastName` (`lastName`),
  KEY `IDX_Person_firstName` (`firstName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Mapping: Document**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Document extends BaseEntity<Integer>
{
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sectionId")
    private Section section;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "currentRevisionId")
    private DocumentRevision currentRevision;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<DocumentRevision> documentRevisions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Mapping: DocumentRevision**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DocumentRevision")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class DocumentRevision extends BaseEntity<Integer>
{
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentId", nullable = false)
    private Document document;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "uploaderId")
    private User uploader;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "approverId")
    private User approver;

    @Column
    private String source;

    // other fields removed for brevity
}
```

**Mapping: User**

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User extends BaseEntity<UUID>
{
    @Column(length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String primaryEmailAddress;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean hidden;
}
```

I realize this is a lot of information, but this one's got me stumped!

Comment: I'm curious why you're using binary for the SQL type of the user's ID and BTW, where is that ID mapped in your Java class?

Comment: `User.id` is a `UUID` / GUID, so it's stored as binary. The `id` field is defined in the super class (updated to show that).

Comment: I think this will require debugging through Hibernate to the point where it is fetching eager relationships. Do you have a minimal reproducer project by chance?

Comment: Yeah, we spent a couple days on this but had to move on. Changing one of the relationships to be `FetchType.LAZY` is the workaround.

Comment: Logged a bug w/Hibernate ORM: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14481

Comment: UUIDs are inefficient on _huge_ tables.

Comment: @RickJames we generally use numeric PKs, and that table up there is decently sized but not giant. Thanks for the input, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into this problem again a while back, and then just last week. I did some more messing around and was able to fix it by upgrading the MySQL Connector dependency from `6.0.6` to `8.0.22`.